# How to highlight specific lines in specific groups with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to highlight (change the color) specific lines in a plot.

The input data looks like this:

```
dt <- data.frame(Marker = paste0('m', rep(seq(1,10), 10)),
                 Year = rep(1990:1999, each = 10),
                 Ahat = rnorm(100, 0.5, 0.1)) %>% 
  mutate(Group = if_else(Marker %in% c("m1", "m2", "m3"), "A", 
                         if_else(Marker %in% c("m4", "m5", "m6"), "B", 
                         if_else(Marker %in% c("m7", "m8"), "C", "D")) ) )
```

And the general plot can be created by:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x = Year, y = Ahat, group = interaction(as.factor(Group), Marker), color = as.factor(Group) ) ) + 
  geom_line(alpha = 0.5, size = 0.5) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Predicted Value", breaks = pretty_breaks()) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Groups", values = c("black", "red", "blue", "orange")) +
  facet_wrap(~Group)
```

[image]

What I'd like to do is to highlight (e.g. make some lines black) some specific lines in specific groups (e.g. "m1" and "m9").
I've tried using something like this `gghighlight(Marker %in% c("m1", "m9"))`, but it doesn't work.

I'd like to have something like this (sorry for my poor drawing skills):
[image]

Any suggestion?

P.S: My real data has 50K markers.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by "highlight"?

Comment: Hi @BroVic, I mean to change the color (and `alpha`) of some specific lines. Let's say, using the example that I've mentioned, make the lines of "m1" and "m9" black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to first group data in subgroups (nesting in the dataframe) and then build the plots...

````
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(patchwork)

# 1. Create dataframe ----
dt <- data.frame(Marker = as.factor(paste0('m', rep(seq(1,10), 10))),
                 Year = rep(1990:1999, each = 10),
                 Ahat = rnorm(100, 0.5, 0.1)) %>% 
  mutate(Group = case_when(
    Marker %in% c("m1", "m2", "m3") ~ "A", 
    Marker %in% c("m4", "m5", "m6") ~ "B", 
    Marker %in% c("m7", "m8")       ~ "C",
    TRUE ~ "D"))


# 2. Function to choose which Market of sub_df should be Highlight
getHighlightMarketBasedOntAhatValue <- function(sub_dt) {
  sub_dt <- sub_dt %>% 
    group_by(Marker) %>% 
    mutate(mean_Ahat = mean(Ahat))
  # using mean to choose Ahat is just a doomed example... also instead of a single value you could get an array of values.
# Here I am not using the index...1, 2... any more (as was in first solution), but the factor itself.
  highlightMarket <- first(sub_dt$Marker[sub_dt$mean_Ahat == max(sub_dt$mean_Ahat)])
}

# 3. Function to build plot for sub_df
my_plot <- function(sub_dt, highlighted_one) {
  custom_pallete = rep("grey", length(levels(sub_dt$Marker)))
  names(custom_pallete) <- levels(sub_dt$Marker)
  custom_pallete[highlighted_one] = "blue"
  
  dt %>% ggplot(aes(x = Year, 
                    y = Ahat, 
                    color = as.factor(Marker))) + 
    geom_line(alpha = 0.5, size = 0.5) +
    theme_classic() +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Predicted Value", breaks = pretty_breaks()) +
    scale_colour_manual(name = "Marker", values = custom_pallete)
}

# 4. Main ----

# 4.1 Nesting ----
nested_dt <- dt %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  nest()

# 4.2 Choosing highlight Market for each subgroup ----
nested_dt <- nested_dt %>% 
  mutate(highlighted_one = getHighlightMarketBasedOntAhatValue(data[[1]]))

# 4.3 Build plots ----
nested_dt <- nested_dt %>% 
  mutate(plot = map2(.x = data,
                     .y = highlighted_one,
                     .f = ~ my_plot(.x, .y)))

# 4.4 Use patchwork ... ----
# to combine plots ... see patchwork help to find out how to 
# manage titles, labels, etc.
nested_dt %>% pull(plot) %>% patchwork::wrap_plots()

```
````

Comment: Hi @abreums, thank you. This is an interesting way to see this problem. In this case, you're highlighting the second line of each group, right? In my case though, I won't have this kind of pattern. I'll select some `Markers` based on their `Ahat` value. So I'd need a vector of names (m1, m4, m9) of positions (1,4,9) in `highlight_ones`

Comment: That's why I provide a second solution in the commented code. In your question, you mention a prioritization as "c("m1", "m9")". The same way in the second solution I  suggested *highlight_ones = c(1,2,1,2)*. You can construct this criterion outside the plot function or even inside it. Anyway, this is the part of your problem that I didn't understand.

Comment: Hmm you are right. I think this second `highlight_ones = c(1,2,1,2)` can help solving my problem. The only limitation I guess is that I can highlight just one `Marker`per group, right? But that already helps a lot. Thank you!

Comment: I rebuild my answer to show how to do it. You can highlight many lines if you work the *custom_pallete* inside *my_plot* method. Instead of passing one Market value, you can for example pass an array with factors reordered to different colors.

Comment: Also, I think with some effort any solution with *nesting* may be rewritten with *group_by* (and facet_wrap) as you originally were searching for... but to build this ... it would be necessary to know the highlight criteria ... because it would be part of the solution. Although my proposal would be better if the criteria should be opened to change.

Comment: I just remembered this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rz3_FDVt9eg&t=2761s from Hadley Wickham... it seems to be very similar problem @godines.

Comment: Thank you @abreums. This `nest()` function seems pretty nice!

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to set `color` as `Marker`.
Then you can change the color of the `Marker` in this line

`scale_colour_manual(name = "Groups", values = c("black", "red", "blue", "orange", "green", "black", "red", "blue", "orange", "green")) +`

Change the colors as you like:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x = Year, y = Ahat, group = interaction(as.factor(Group), Marker), color = Marker ) ) + 
  geom_line(alpha = 0.5, size = 0.5) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Predicted Value", breaks = pretty_breaks()) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Groups", values = c("black", "red", "blue", "orange", "green",
                                                  "black", "red", "blue", "orange", "green")) +
  facet_wrap(~Group)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @TarJae. The problem is that my real data has 50K markers. So to manually set these colors might be a problem. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks!